# Teams crashes when sharing entire screen and notebook connected to ultrawide monitor

Tags: windows, microsoft-teams

I'm currently running the Teams app 1.3.00.24755 (64 bit) running on Windows version 1909 and build 18363.1082. The notebook is connected to a 35“ Ultrawide Curved Monitor from LG.. Notebook display scale 125% and resolution 1920 x 1080 Ultrawide monitor scale 125% and resoluton 3440 x 1440

When I am on a call and share the entire screen of the notebook or of the ultrawide monitor, the teams app completely crashes.

Relevant errors in the log file:

<9768> -- error -- [screenSharing][control] appSharingToolbar: sendMessage failed: the tooblbar does not exist <9768> -- error -- Unhandled exception occured <9768> -- error -- Unhandled exception occured TypeError: Cannot read property 'showInactive' of null at WebContents.appSharingToolbarWindow.webContents.on (Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\appSharingToolbar.js:307:46) at WebContents.emit (events.js:190:5) <9768> -- event -- name: desktop_uncaught_exception, isOnBattery: false, remainingBatteryPercentage: 100, errorStackTraceV2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showInactive' of null at WebContents.appSharingToolbarWindow.webContents.on (Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\appSharingToolbar.js:307:46) at WebContents.emit (events.js:190:5), vdiMode: 0, eventpdclevel: 1, <9768> -- event -- isOnBattery: false, remainingBatteryPercentage: 100, errorStackTraceV2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showInactive' of null at WebContents.appSharingToolbarWindow.webContents.on (Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\appSharingToolbar.js:307:46) at WebContents.emit (events.js:190:5), vdiMode: 0, status: success, scenario: b98eff4e-e661-4551-965f-aa40bcbc0ab5, scenarioName: desktop_uncaught_exception, name: desktop_uncaught_exception, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 92411036, stepDelta: 0, eventpdclevel: 3, Scenario.Name: desktop_uncaught_exception, Scenario.Step: start, Scenario.Status: success, <9768> -- event -- isOnBattery: false, remainingBatteryPercentage: 100, errorStackTraceV2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showInactive' of null at WebContents.appSharingToolbarWindow.webContents.on (Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\appSharingToolbar.js:307:46) at WebContents.emit (events.js:190:5), vdiMode: 0, status: success, scenario: b98eff4e-e661-4551-965f-aa40bcbc0ab5, scenarioName: desktop_uncaught_exception, name: desktop_uncaught_exception, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 2, scenarioDelta: 2, elapsed: 92411038, stepDelta: 2, eventpdclevel: 3, Scenario.Name: desktop_uncaught_exception, Scenario.Step: stop, Scenario.Status: success,

<9768> -- error -- [screenSharing][control] appSharingToolbar: "this" does not bind to AppSharingToolbar object in closeWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the newest graphic drivers for your computer (check also the manufacturers page, e.g. if you have an HP you can use HP Support assistant), this looks like a driver problem.